# how to disable rotation in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I would like to support only portrait view. How can I make a React Native app not to autorotate?
I tried searching documentation and Github issues, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Cannot you just set the supported orientations in the application properties (same as with any other iOS app)?

Comment: What about Android?

Comment: @ooolala answer in this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078354/how-to-disable-landscape-mode-in-react-native-android-dev-mode

Comment: NOTE: On my MOTO 4, I couldn't get `sensorPortrait` to work properly. It would never support upside down Portrait (i.e. `reversePortrait`). However, using `fullSensor` did work but it had the caveat of also allowing landscape. That ended up being fine for me but if you only want `portrait` and `reversePortrait`, you can intercept the orientation change in your Activity with `onConfigurationChanged` and `newConfig.orientation` and just ignore or override landscape changes.

Comment: How about disabling mobile screen rotation in React? (not React Native) Meta tag not working.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

React Native app is pretty much just a normal iOS application, so you can do it in exactly the same way as you do for all other apps. Simply uncheck (in XCode) the "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" as allowed Device Orientations in the General application properties:

[image: Device orientation]

Comment: thx! one more question, I checked `portrait` and `upside down`, but my app didn't autorotate when I rotate simulator's screen (90 degree twice), what's the problem?

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't seem to work with RN 34 when running on an iPad (Pro) simulator. It does, however, work when running on an iPhone simulator. I need it to work on an iPad though. Strange.

Comment: Turns out I need to set "Devices" as iPad and not "Universal" like it was before. That made it work.

Comment: Mr @Jarek Potiuk i have a small doubt, actually when i was run my simulater defaultly shows landscapemode, i had use landscapeleft& right . but, rightnow its not show the landscape mode in device. i am using react native orientation module and in xcode select landscape left & right. but, i didn't get

Comment: I think the reason why a lot of questions are asked specific to React Native is because a lot of web devs like me don't really know much about native app development. Thanks though!

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason anymore. At least not in `react-native 0.45.1`

Comment: When I try to upload to appstore testflight I get this if landscape isn't enabled.
`ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown'`

We need to support both iphone and ipad but only in portrait mode.

Comment: ITSM-90474 error solved by selecting the `Requires full screen` option too

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
For the android 
1. Open YourProject -> android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml
2. Put android:screenOrientation=“portrait” in <application>
as shown below https://aboutreact.com/react-native-disable-screen-rotation/

Answer (score 159):

For iOS, Jarek's answer is great.

For Android, you need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file. Add the following line to each activity that you want to lock into portrait mode:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

So, a full example might look like this:

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

See full list of available screenOrientation properties in the docs, here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just for the benefit of others who are using VS Code: execute 'Run Android on Device/Simulator' from 'Command Palette...'. Shaking the device to 'Reload' the app will not work.

Comment: It does not work on Android. Any ideas how lock orientation of all app?

Answer (score 82):

### 2017 Update: `{"orientation": "portrait"}`

Currently many official React Native guides like [this one](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html) recommend using Expo when building React Native apps so in addition to existing answers I'll also add an Expo-specific solution which is worth noting because it works for both iOS and Android and you only need to set it once with no need to mess with XCode config, AndroidManifest.xml etc.

### Setting orientation at build time:

If you're building your React Native apps with Expo then you can use the `orientation` field in your `app.json` file - for example:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
    "privacy": "public",
    "orientation": "portrait"
  }
}
```

It can be set to `"portrait"`, `"landscape"` or `"default"` which means to autorotate with no orientation lock.

### Setting orientation at runtime:

You can also override that setting at runtime by running, for example:

```
Expo.ScreenOrientation.allow(Expo.ScreenOrientation.Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

where the argument can be:

- `ALL` — All 4 possible orientations
- `ALL_BUT_UPSIDE_DOWN` — All but reverse portrait, could be all 4 orientations on certain Android devices.
- `PORTRAIT` — Portrait orientation, could also be reverse portrait on certain Android devices.
- `PORTRAIT_UP` — Upside portrait only.
- `PORTRAIT_DOWN` — Upside down portrait only.
- `LANDSCAPE` — Any landscape orientation.
- `LANDSCAPE_LEFT` — Left landscape only.
- `LANDSCAPE_RIGHT` — Right landscape only.

### Detecting the rotation:

When you allow more than one orientation then you can detect the changes by listening to the `change` events on the `Dimensions` object:

```
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', (dimensions) => {
  // you get:
  //  dimensions.window.width
  //  dimensions.window.height
  //  dimensions.screen.width
  //  dimensions.screen.height
});
```

or you can also just get the dimensions anytime with `Dimensions.get('window')` and `Dimensions.get('screen')` like this:

```
const dim = Dimensions.get('window');
// you get:
//  dim.width
//  dim.height
```

or:

```
const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
// you get:
//  dim.width
//  dim.height
```

When you listen to the event you get both `window` and `screen` at the same time so that's why you access it differently.

### Documentation:

For more info see:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#orientation
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

Comment: works after I closed expo on the device and relaunch

Comment: Is there way to separate it, Like Ipad allow landscape and Iphone only portrait ?

Comment: This is the solution that works in my case. My main view make a 180 deg rotation after closing interstitial ad. So I should make a hard coded 
    Expo.ScreenOrientation.allowAsync(Expo.ScreenOrientation.Orientation.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);

Comment: Thanks. add  `"orientation": "portrait"` is working in react-native-cli either

Answer (score 50):

**`Answer for disable rotation in React Native.`**

**`For Android :`**

Go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add one line : **android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

```
         <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
```

**`For IOS :`**

Simple you have to check or uncheck rotation mode from your XCODE

[image]

Comment: Best answer in 2020, that covers both iOS and Android

Comment: Nice answer. ankit

Comment: Hi, I changed my orientation in my app.json to "portrait" and still when i rotate my device, the items on the screen dont rotate but when i press of a text input the keyboard is rotated. Why is that happening?

Comment: It does not work on Android. Any ideas how lock orientation of all app?

Answer (score 13):

If you're using **react-navigation** then you can simply pass

```
screenOptions={{ orientation: 'portrait'}}
```

For Stack Navigation, we can pass this property either like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Muhammed,

Can you provide a little more detailed code? Where we should put screenOptions?

Thanks!

Comment: @TahaAteş I have added an example, hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 7):

For Android, you need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file. Add the following line to each activity that you want to lock into portrait mode:

**android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

So, a full example might look like this:

```
 <application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: It does not work on Android. Any ideas how lock orientation of all app?

Answer (score 7):

For Android:
In your manifest file put:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then inside the application tag put:

```
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```

And then in all activity set:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: It does not work on Android. Any ideas how lock orientation of all app?

Answer (score 3):

If you using Expo you can do it simply with this code:

```
Expo.ScreenOrientation.allow(Expo.ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT);
```

Put it on App.js before render

All options:

`ALL` 
`ALL_BUT_UPSIDE_DOWN`
`PORTRAIT` 
`PORTRAIT_UP` 
`PORTRAIT_DOWN`
`LANDSCAPE` 
`LANDSCAPE_LEFT`
`LANDSCAPE_RIGHT`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker) module and `lockToPortrait()` function.
This can be helpful if you would also like to have some of the screens with unlocked orientation - in this case you could also use `unlockAllOrientations()` function.

Answer (score 1):

use this for ios ipad orientaion issue want to change in plist file https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/7vkrfp/disabling_screen_rotate_in_react_native_both/

IOS:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key> <array> <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string> <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string> </array>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

For Android open AndroidManifest.xml file then add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to activity tag and your code should be like that.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using RN expo project, and app contains react-navigation, then setting up the navigation to the following code helped me.

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Page1: { screen: Page1}
},
{
    portraitOnlyMode: true
});
```