# How to disable landscape mode in React Native Android dev mode?

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to android environment. I know iOS can be done in Xcode to disable device orientation. How can I disable landscape mode or any orientation mode in React Native Android?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can disable it from manifest file...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode

Comment: 1. Open YourProject -> android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml
2. Put android:screenOrientation=“portrait” in <application> tag
You can see here https://aboutreact.com/react-native-disable-screen-rotation

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the `activity` section in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file, so that it end up looking like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

There are several different values for the `android:screenOrientation` property; for a comprehensive list take a look at the following: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Do we have to do it for every activity?

Comment: You really want to use `sensorPortrait` instead of `portrait` so that it can be used "upside down" as well. And, if you're targeting API 18+, you should use `userPortrait`, as it will respect if the user has locked orientation. See the docs for more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: @Bat ReactNativeNavigation apparently has changed since your comment, and setting `android:screenOrientation` as suggested in the Answer works fine now.

Comment: how can i do it if i want landscape for tab and portrait for mobile device. please help. @Gem Ubaldo

Answer (score 49):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your activity xml

Comment: has the approach changed? please let us know, these apis are constantly changing

Comment: Make sure to put it in the activity tag and not in application tag!

Comment: how can i do it if i want landscape for tab and portrait for mobile device. please help.

Answer (score 33):

As @morenoh149 stated above the property name and value to do this is android:screenOrientation="portrait".  React Native generates a file called AndroidManifest.xml in your project directory under the Android folder.  Within that xml file under the tag manifest/application/activity you would add the line **android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

An example is shown below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: I like this answer best because it shows exactly where to put changes.

Comment: Does not work. I change orientation from emulator, and the app view changes to landscape

Comment: how can i do it if i want landscape for tab and portrait for mobile device. please help.

Answer (score 17):

Harry Moreno's comment is correct.  Add it to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml in the 'activity' section. Also change

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

to
`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

removing orientation so it doesn't conflict with the new line added, 
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what @mixophrygian says if you want to do what OP wants. Which is to completely disable landscape view. However, if somewhere in your app you want the user to view things landscape then don't remove it. There won't be any conflict (there's also no conflict if you leave this in regardless).

Answer (score 15):

### 2017 Update

In addition to the solutions posted above if you're using Expo to build your app (as is currently recommended in official guides on [React Native Blog](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/)) then all you need is to set `orientation` in `app.json` to "portrait" or "landscape" and make it work on both iOS and Android at the same time with no need to edit iOS/Android-specific XML configuration files:

#### `"orientation": "portrait"`

Example:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
    "privacy": "public",
    "orientation": "portrait"
  }
}
```

You can also use this at runtime:

#### `ScreenOrientation.allow()`

Example:

```
ScreenOrientation.allow(ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT);
```

#### More details:

For more info see:
**[how to disable rotation in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176548/how-to-disable-rotation-in-react-native/46671734#46671734)**

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer doesn't work if you're using `react-native-navigation`. Use this instead:

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
    layout: {
        orientation: ["portrait"],
    },
});
```

Check the docs [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/options-migration?id=orientation).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply the logic by adding a lifecycle callback in `ReactApplication` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();  

  registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
                // Here we specify to force portrait at each start of any Activity
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

            }
        });
}
```

So you don't need to configure `AndroidManifest`

Comment: This fit my needs to lock orientation only in smartphone devices and remain free orientation on tablets, I just did a device check before  activity.setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Updating `AndroidManifest.xml` had no effect; not sure if I just wasn't publishing it properly. I found I had to call `setRequestedOrientation` in `onActivityResumed` and `onActivityStarted` too.

Answer (score 3):

Just open your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

And add this line `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and  `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize`
inside activity section

It looks something like that

```
 <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
     .....your other stuff
 </activity>
```

If it does not work than you can use
[react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

For React Native Navigation it could be fixed with defining orientation as described [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/style-orientation/):

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
  layout: {
    orientation: ['portrait']
  }
});
```