# Disable rotation for specific views in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I disable rotation only for specific views (e.g: when using Navigator) and not for the entire app?

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176548/how-to-disable-rotation-in-react-native) already addresses disabling rotation for the entire app

Answer (score 5):

With the `react-native-orientation` package, it's possible to lock the orientation to portrait/landscape. The package and documentation can be found here: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation

Remember; you should not put your locking inside the rendering of scenes (nor the `renderScene` method). Since the Navigator re-renders all the scenes in the route stack, this would probably cause weird side effects for you. Rather, the locking/unlocking should be put in the code that interacts with the route stack (ie. calls the `push`/`pop` methods).

Comment: Is it still working? I found lots of forgotten issues, and the module's last update seems to be about 3 years ago

Answer (score 2):

If your case is about more specific control over orientations of different screens in StackNavigator (something like `Portrait -> LandscapeLeft -> LandscapeRight -> Portrait`, and all the way back), here is a may-not-that-pretty solution:

- packages needed: [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html), [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation);
- define base screens as follow:

  ```
  // baseScreen.js
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import Orientation from "react-native-orientation";

  export class PortraitScreen extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this._willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", payload => {
              // lock to portrait when this screen is about to appear
              Orientation.lockToPortrait();
          })
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
          // remove subscription when unmount
          this._willFocusSubscription.remove();
      }
  }

  export class LandscapeScreen extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this._willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", payload => {
              // lock to landscape
              Orientation.lockToLandscape();
          })
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
          // remove subscription either
          this._willFocusSubscription.remove();
      }
  }
  ```
- define concrete screens which extends abovementioned base screen(s):

  ```
  // moduleScreens.js
  import React from "react";
  import { Button, View } from "react-native";
  import { PortraitScreen, LandscapeScreen } from "/path/to/baseScreen";

  export class VideoDescScreen extends PortraitScreen {
      render() {
          return (
              <View>
                  <Button 
                      title="watch video"
                      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("VideoPlayer")}    
                  />
              </View>
          )
      }
  }

  export class VideoPlayerScreen extends LandscapeScreen {
      render() {
          return <View>...</View>
      }
  }
  ```
- create route like this:

  ```
  // route.js
  import React from "react";
  import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
  import { VideoDescScreen, VideoPlayerScreen } from "/path/to/moduleScreens";

  const stack = createStackNavigator(
      {
          VideoDesc: {
              screen: VideoDescScreen
          },
          VideoPlayer: {
              screen: VideoPlayerScreen
          }
      }
  )
  ```
- How it works? According to [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle), we observe event `willFocus` when screen is initialized, and each time this screen is about to appear (focused) in navigation, we lock device to our desired orientation, works for both PUSH(to) and POP(back from) behaviors.

Hope it helps.