# How to disable screen rotation (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Is any chance to disable screen rotation (allow only vertical)? I would like to support only portrait view. And need it to work on android and ios.

Comment: check this answer out for ios - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176548/how-to-disable-rotation-in-react-native?rq=1

Comment: If using CRNA apps, use the `app.json` file to set `orientation` as either potrait or landscape. See here for more details: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration#orientationlock-your-app-to-a-specific-orientation-with-portrait-or-landscape-defaults-to-no-lock-valid-values-default-portrait-landscape

Comment: Please check this article from the medium- https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-portrait-device-orientation-9bcdeeac0b03

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to disable rotation in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176548/how-to-disable-rotation-in-react-native)

Answer (score 8):

Add screenOrientation in your Manifest.xml class

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the below code in manifest file

```html
<activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the below code in manifest file

```
<activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In android :-

using xml :-`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

using java :-

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: Please be clear with your answer, also the question is for both iOs and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Winner:  chuck this in the app code, I usually drop it right after all my imports.

Expo.ScreenOrientation.allow(Expo.ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Android's official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

You just have to add this to your activity tag in your android `MANIFEST` file :

```
<activity 
  android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
    "landscape" | "portrait" |
    "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
    "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
    "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
    "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
    "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```

using the orientation that you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this in config.xml

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Comment: This applies to Cordova/Phonegap, not React Native.