# it's impossible react-native lock screen rotation with NATIVE framework components?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

Is there a possibility that I can force a single View in the entire project to always be in portrait without relying on external dependencies?

I admit that I am new to "React-native" and simply everything I search returns some NPM package to solve the problem.

I cannot accept that such a strong tool has no native resources to solve this type of situation

Obs: I am not using **EXPO** in this project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176548/how-to-disable-rotation-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) inside the screen you want to rotate for that for example:

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

useEffect(()=>{
    Orientation.lockToLandscape()
},[])
```